# Why .NET 3.5 SP1 has special meaning for Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, .net-framework, microsoft

According to this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework

.NET 3.5 SP1 retire date is 2029 which sets it aside from other .NET versions.

There is footnote:

```
NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (SP1) is a standalone product following the Fixed Policy,
beginning with Windows 10 version 1809 and Windows Server 2019. Prior to this, 
.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is considered a component of the Windows operating system on which it is installed.
```

I havent installed 3.5 for years and my Windows 10 and 11 work just fine.

**Why is it so important to keep it alive longer than most .NET versions?**

Comment: I havent installed 3.5 for years   .... It is updated along with other .NET updates which occur roughly montthly.

Comment: I dont know how is it "updated" if it is not installed at all..

Comment: Look in Control Panel, Programs and Features, Windows Features.  .NET 3.5 is normally enabled there as well as .NET 4.8

Comment: We can't say. We can have opinions but we're not Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it so important to keep it alive longer than most .NET versions?

`Windows Server 2019` is supported until January 9th, 2029, the exact date, `.NET Framework 3.5` is also supported until. Microsoft routinely supports components like `.NET Framework 3.5` until the relevant version of Windows is no longer supported.
`Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019`, based on 1809, is also supported until January 9th, 2029.

This is why both `Windows Server 2019` and ``Windows 10 1809 are explicitly mentioned in the footnotes in the lifecycle notification for `.NET Framework 3.5`.  Microsoft routinely supports optional features until the relevant versions of Windows are no longer supported.

There isn't anything special about the optional Windows component `.NET Framework 3.5`. **It's important to understand that `.NET Framework 3.5` on Windows 10 1809 and Windows Server 2019 is a standalone product, who's lifecycle, is linked to those two versions.**
Sources:

1. [Windows Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-server-2019)
2. [Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-enterprise-ltsc-2019)